# Is it possible to declare variables without @ symbol in sql-server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables

I have this scenario where I can't use @ signs in the sql. However I would like to declare variables. Does anyone know if there is any other way to declare them without using the @ sign?

Comment: Is your keyboard broken?

Comment: I want to know what is that scenario where you can't use @ sign. It will be really interesting to know

Comment: If you can't use @ signs then use @@ symbol to declare as a global variable. :-)

Comment: hahahahaha im sory but i have too. Tell us the problem instead we may provide an alternative solution

Comment: So, wait, your solution oto avoiding the `@` symbol is to use 2 of them, @@Santhana ..? O.o

Comment: `SELECT CHAR(64)`

Comment: Dont keep us waiting, tell us that scenario where you cannot use @

Comment: You could switch to another database that does not use @ for variables

Comment: This sounds rather funny, but my magic crystal ball tells me, that this might be connected to a known problem on RPC connected desktops. Sometimes we just can't type the `@`... I this case *copy-and-paste* helps a lot. If this is the case, you can execute `SELECT CHAR(64)` and take the character with `ctrl+c` and paste it with `ctrl+v`. Just guessing...

Comment: stackoverflow should have a "MacGyver" badge given to accepted solutions to questions like these.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A workaround is to use temporary tables. This adds a lot of overhead, affects query plans and requires a lot more code to achieve the same functionality, but you can get it to work.

Please beware that they are not variables, you can't use variables without the `@`.

Say you can't do this:

```
DECLARE @FilterDate DATE = '2019-01-01'
DECLARE @FilterInt INT = 20

SELECT
    T.*
FROM
    SomeTable AS T
WHERE
    T.Date > @FilterDate AND
    T.Integer > @FilterInt
```

The workaround with temporary table:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Variables') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Variables

CREATE TABLE #Variables (
    VariableName VARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY,
    Value VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #Variables (
    VariableName,
    Value)
VALUES
    ('FilterDate', '2019-01-01'),
    ('FilterInt', '20')

SELECT
    T.*
FROM
    SomeTable AS T
WHERE
    T.Date > (SELECT CONVERT(DATE, V.Value) FROM #Variables AS V WHERE V.VariableName = 'FilterDate') AND
    T.Integer > (SELECT CONVERT(INT, V.Value) FROM #Variables AS V WHERE V.VariableName = 'FilterInt')
```

Although with a weird requirement to not use `@`, you might not be able to use `#` either...

Comment: "Although with a weird requirement to not use @, you might not be able to use # either.." :) +1

Comment: Is a temporary table a variable?

Comment: It should be noted that if you can hand-code the variables into a temporary table insert function, you can hand-code them into the original query. Just sayin'

Comment: YES, YOU CAN :D!!! With... * "'gasp...!!!!!'" * "'SQL Injection...!!!!!'"
YEAH, VERY, VERY, MUCH, TOO, "'HACKY;'"
BUT... IT DOES THE "'JOB...!!!'" YOU, CAN, ALSO; pretty much 
"'@void'" the "'1ssues,'"
by "'formatt1ng'" the "'Sp3c1@L ch@r@ct3r5...!!!!!'"

Answer (score 1):

You are out of luck here:

> The DECLARE statement initializes a Transact-SQL variable by:
>
> Assigning a name. **The name must have a single @ as the first
>   character.**
>
> Assigning a system-supplied or user-defined data type and a length.
>   For numeric variables, a precision and scale are also assigned. For
>   variables of type XML, an optional schema collection may be assigned.
>
> Setting the value to NULL.

[Variables (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/variables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temporary table. It will not perform as well, but if that is not a problem to you, then this might solve your problem with the @ sign. Have a look at this example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#var') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #var;
CREATE TABLE #var (var1 int);
INSERT INTO #var (var1) VALUES (12);
SELECT var1 FROM #var;
UPDATE #var SET var1 = 34;
SELECT var1 FROM #var;
```